# Find/replace on two html tags with regex

Tags: regex

I am looking to capture two html tags' content with regex. For actual html parsing I would use something else, but I'm operating in a find/replace from a text editor so I only have regex as an option for this particular task. The text is:

```
<meta property="og:type" content= "website"/>
<meta content= "something" property="og:new" />
...and several more below...
```

I have the following to capture the first, but it gets tricky when doing the alternation in the order of the tags:

```
meta\s(property=")(?P<prop>[^"]+)"\s(content= ")(?P<value>[^"]+)"\/>|
```

How could I do the above with a regex?

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a job for [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
<meta\s(?=.*?property\s*=\s*"([^"]+))(?=.*?content\s*=\s*"([^"]+)).+/>
```

**Explanation:**

```
<meta\s             # openning tag followed by a space
(?=                 # start lookahead, zero-length assertion that checks we have after:
    .*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    property            # literally
    \s*=\s*             # equal sign surround by optional spaces
    "                   # double quote
    ([^"]+)             # group 1, 1 or more non quote
)                   # end lookahead
(?=                 # start lookahead, zero-length assertion that checks we have after:
    .*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    content             # literally
    \s*=\s*             # equal sign surround by optional spaces
    "                   # double quote
    ([^"]+)             # group 2, 1 or more non quote
)                   # end lookahead
.+/>                # 1 or more any character end closing tag
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7AwAKX/1)

Comment: thanks for this great answer! I never knew you could also do capturing with a lookahead, this is great!!

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much easier to do that with two expressions,

```
<meta\s(property=")([^"]+)"\s+(content=")([^"]+)"\s*\/>
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/CuSrlj/1/)

```
<meta\s(content=")([^"]+)"\s+(property=")([^"]+)"\s*\/>
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/LjATBj/1/)

and you can replace with anything that you want to.